# How to merge two dataframes without getting additional rows?

Tags: python, pandas

Basically, I have two dataframes, the first one looks like this:

[image: df1]

And the second one like this:

[image: df2]

I want to get the columns "lat" and "lnt" of the second one and add to the first one only if the name of the city matches in both dataframes. I tried using `pd.merge()`, but it's creating new rows with duplicated values.
If possible, I would like to put a NaN in the rows which didn't have any match at all, but I don't want to remove nor add rows to the original dataframe.

Comment: So you want to left join `df1` with `df2` on `city`? If you are getting more rows than what were originally present on `df1`then it means that some `city` appears more than once in `df2`. Can you share your `pd.merge()` call?

Comment: You were right, i checked the second df and it had duplicated values (dont't understand why, since it's the coordinates of every citiy in the us) , i droped them and now it works accordingly, thanks! Sorry for the basic mistake, i'm very new to pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Pandas merge function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) defaults to an inner join. Since you're looking to merge in the columns of `df2` to `df1`, you should use a left join. This will give you all the rows of `df1`, and the matching values from `df2`.

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on = 'city', how = 'left')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merged_df = df1.merge(df2, how = 'inner', on = ['City'])
```